# create a dynamic query using cmd.parameter c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, dynamicquery

I know there are many questions related to create a dynamic query but no one can help me.
I am trying to create a dynamic `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` with the help of `foreach` loop but I can't find all the values that I pass in `foeach`. I know I am writing **var values = " "** that's way the values give me `null` value

I am providing my code may that help you to solve an error

```
  public void insert_Para(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl ControlName, String TableName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString()))
        {
            var values = "";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into "+ TableName +" values(" + values + ")", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (var item in ControlName.Controls)
            {
                if (item is TextBox)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + ((TextBox)item).ID, ((TextBox)item).Text);
                    values += "@" + ((TextBox)item).ID + ",";
                }
            }

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that the string to create the insert statement was already set. If you change `values` you won't change the string from the SqlCommand

Comment: @MarcGravell the query itself is just an `INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES()` without any parameters *or* values. The conditional block adds a parameter without actualy changing the query.

Comment: This code is neither dynamic nor does it use any parameters. `values` is empty when the query is constructed which means the SqlCommand object tries to execute an invalid query against some table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it was clearly *intended* to be parameterized, contrary to the comment that I was replying to; the fact that it doesn't work shouldn't surprise us - if the code was working as expected, we rarely see a question here about that :)

Comment: as a side note: you're going to be *very* vulnerable to the order of the controls if this is how you create the SQL - right now it is assumed that the control order exactly matches the column order

Comment: you right @panagiotis-kanavos query itself is just an INSERT INTO `SomeTable VALUES()` but want values in `values` parameter. for that what can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is mostly one of timing. You are currently concatenating `values` into the string *right at the start*, when it is an empty string. Once you've done that: *that's it* - that's the SQL you've created:

```
insert into Foo values()
```

which isn't going to help. I would either defer that concatenation until *after* the loop:

```
foreach (var item in ControlName.Controls)
{
    if (item is TextBox)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + ((TextBox)item).ID, ((TextBox)item).Text);
        values += "@" + ((TextBox)item).ID + ",";
    }
}
cmd.CommandText = "insert into "+ TableName +" values(" + values + ")";
```

or I'd use a `StringBuilder` throughout:

```
var sql = new StringBuilder("insert into [").Append(TableName)
              .Append("] values(");
foreach (var item in ControlName.Controls)
{
    if (item is TextBox)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + ((TextBox)item).ID, ((TextBox)item).Text);
        sql.Append("@").Append(((TextBox)item).ID).Append(",");
    }
}
cmd.CommandText = sql.Append(")").ToString();
```

Note also: this is `CommandType.CommandText`, not `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try thi code.

```
  public void Insert_Data_generic(DataSet dsins)
  {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        string Result = "insert into TableName (";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();    
        con.Open();
        string columns = string.Join(",", dsins.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName));
        string values = string.Join(",", dsins.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => string.Format("@{0}", c.ColumnName)));

        Result += columns + ") values(" + values + ")";
        foreach (DataRow row in dsins.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Result, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dsins.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + col.ColumnName, row[col]);

            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
```

Comment: You assume @Minhaj Patel has a DataSet. This also requires additional calls to the database to get the meta-data (column names). You are not supplying the values from the TextBox in the OP. You are not disposing of SqlConnection or SqlCommand.